# Tibco Spotfire, Tibco Analyst/ TDV connectivity to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake, spotfire, azure-data-lake-gen2, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

Tibco spotfire is good for dashboards, but can't see any Azure data-source adapters in TDV, Anyway to seamless connect Azure with Spotfire for realtime dashboards, perhaps without synapse !?

Comment: Hi @Denize, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Leon Yue., Thank you, indeed I surfed the internet before posting the question, cdata is third party adapter, wonder if there is something within spotfire or azure before considering a customized connector using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You can ref this tutorial: [Visualize Azure Data Lake Storage Data in TIBCO Spotfire through ADO.NET](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/azuredatalake-ado-spotfire.rst):

- This article walks you through using the CData ADO.NET Provider for
  Azure Data Lake Storage in TIBCO Spotfire. You will establish a
  connection and create a simple dashboard.

It shows the example and may can give some guides.